# Stacking multiple arrays with multiple dimensions python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create and stack multiple multi-dimensional arrays in python and I seem not to be able to get it right.

I have:

```
   y_0 = np.random.uniform(-1.0,1.0, size=(1,1,s_conn.weights.shape[0],1))
   y_1 = np.random.uniform(-500.0, 500.0, size=(1,1,s_conn.weights.shape[0],1))
   y_2 = np.random.uniform(-50.,50., size=(1,1,s_conn.weights.shape[0],1))
   y_3 = np.random.uniform(-6.0, 6.0, size=(1,1,s_conn.weights.shape[0],1))
   y_4 = np.random.uniform(-20.0, 20.0, size=(1,1,s_conn.weights.shape[0],1))
   y_5 = np.random.uniform(-500.,500., size=(1,1,s_conn.weights.shape[0],1))
```

where s.conn is NxN matrix.

And each array has dims: (1, 1, 10, 1)
What I need is an array of shape: (1, 6, 10, 1)

How do I get that? I tried np.stack and manual creation and reshaping but I keep getting strange/ incorrect outcomes.

I would be grateful for a bit of advice.

js

Comment: concatenate with axis 1?

Answer (score 0):

np.stack joins a sequence of arrays along a new axis, so it will create an undesired dimension to your matrix, consider using np.concatenate.

```
np.concatenate([y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5],axis = 1)
```

Note, your can also use Array.squeeze() to remove undesired dimensions (that may arise when using np.stach without using reshaping, for example the same result can be achived with:

```
np.stack([y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5],axis = 1).squeeze(axis=2)
```

Comment: This is why this website is amazing. Worked like a charm! Thank you